# Kernel route ignored on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, routes

We are having some weird network behaviors on some Linux VMs (cloud based, multiple providers, mostly Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04). We have two distinct networks with a Strongswan gateway in-between.

Site A:
Network - 10.104.16.0/20
VPN gateway and routing configured on the main router (no conf needed on virtual machines)

Site B: 
Network - 10.240.132.0/25
Strongswan gateway - 10.240.132.15
Routing configured per VM depending on the need (or not) to communicate with Site A

Kernel routing table on one of the VMs on Site B which need to communicate with Site A VMs:

```
# route -vn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.240.132.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.104.16.0     10.240.132.15   255.255.240.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.240.132.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

And now, the issue...
When everything works good, the VM does ping VMs on Site A and this is what the traceroute command outputs:

```
# traceroute 10.104.19.4
traceroute to 10.104.19.4 (10.104.19.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.240.132.15 (10.240.132.15)  0.248 ms  0.228 ms  0.220 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.104.19.4 (10.104.19.4)  15.048 ms  15.042 ms  15.028 ms
```

Then suddenly the VM could not ping the Site A resources and the traceroute output would look like this:

```
# traceroute 10.104.19.4
traceroute to 10.104.19.4 (10.104.19.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.104.19.4 (10.104.19.4)  0.552 ms  0.567 ms  0.616 ms
 2  * 10.104.19.4 (10.104.19.4)  0.659 ms  0.707 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *^C
```

It looks completely random tho. When this eventually happens I would remove then add the route again with:

```
# route del -net 10.104.16.0 gw 10.240.132.15 netmask 255.255.240.0
# route add -net 10.104.16.0 gw 10.240.132.15 netmask 255.255.240.0
```

Of course that solves the problem for a while it doesn't last for long... Any idea of what could go wrong or of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you guys ;)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This has stumped me for the last 3 hours; however I had one more clue - my pings returned
a sporadic 'Redirect Host(New nexthop: x.x.x.x)'

I can't figure out why it is happening sporadically either, and refreshing the route certainly fixes it in the short term.

I fixed this issue with disabling icmp redirects.

## echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/accept_redirects

## echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*/accept_redirects

from here ; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57941/linux-always-send-icmp-redirect

Cheers

Martin